# how to select 3 fruit from 4 fruit in sequence and alternately?

Tags: php

for example i have this sequence : orange, banana, apple and raspberry. i want to show 3 data in sequence and alternately like this :

- page refresh 1 show : orange, banana, apple
- page refresh 2 show :banana, apple, raspberry
- page refresh 3 show : apple, respberry,    orange

etc
note : 
the amount of data i want to display changes

i try using `array_push` and `array_pop` but i stuck when i want to random it. here my code :

```
<?php 
$stack = array("orange", "banana"); 
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry"); 
array_pop($stack);
print_r($stack); 
?>
```

can anyone fix my code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: @jeroen would not using shuffle would just random rather than sequentially?

Comment: if you want to keep your sequence, just pick a random number between 0 and the length of your array and pick your 3 elements from this index (you will have to check to restart from the begining if you reach the end of the array)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
function pickElementsFromArray($array, $countToPick)
{
    $start = rand(0, count($array)-1);
    $picked = 0;
    $elements = [];
    while ($picked < $countToPick) {
        $elements[] = $array[$start];
        $start++;
        if ($start >= count($array)) {
            $start = 0;
        }
        $picked++;
    }

    return $elements;
}

$array = ["orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry"];
$elemsToPick = 3;
$elements = pickElementsFromArray($array, $elemsToPick);
```

This functions starts the picking from a random position and from there it picks n elements. if the end of the array is reached, it restarts from the begining

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$fruits=array('orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'raspberry');
function pick($count,$fruits){
    $counter=0;
  for ($i = 0; $i <=count($fruits)+1 ; $i++) {
     if ($i>=$count) {
        if ($counter<=2) {
            if (array_key_exists($i, $fruits)) {
                echo $fruits[$i];
                echo '<br>';
                $counter++;
            }
            else{
                $counter++;
                echo $fruits[0];
            }                       
        }
     }
  }
}

echo pick(0,$fruits);
echo '<br>';
echo pick(1,$fruits);
echo '<br>';
echo pick(2,$fruits);
```

OUTPUT:

orange
banana
apple

banana
apple
raspberry

apple
raspberry
orange